# Allow filtering the low rep vote lists by user

Tags: feature-request, post-feedback

[While discussing information rot on chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3221580#3221580), I argued that really pretty much the only way we have to know if an old answer has effectively rot is by monitoring anonymous feedback, something 10kers can do ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback/least-helpful?filter=all) [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback/least-helpful?filter=all) [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/least-helpful?filter=all) etc.).

The list however is global, and thus not very useful unless you see your own posts towering on this page. It would be more interesting to be able to see how *my very own* posts fare with regard to anonymous feedback.

So, my feature request is being able to filter those lists to only show posts by the active user. Ideally you shouldn't need 10,000 reputation to see this view, given how useful the feedback can be to review your own long tail of answers.

Can has?

Comment: mockups, should this be linked from your user page, where?

Comment: How have I not seen this before? Awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I am not against doing something like this if we nail the UI down.

In the mean time you can use the following data explorer query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60668/feedback-on-my-posts

I had a look at my list and in general there is not enough signal yet.

Comment: I dunno, [switching around the ordering](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/revision/60678/62145/negative-feedback-on-my-posts) and running it against my Gaming account (23) got me [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17289) (which isn't really mine), [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6925) (which is out of date) and [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/10530/23) (which is also out of date).

Comment: As for the UI, how about a "my posts" tab in /review?